# .get not working in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import os


name = input("Please enter your username ") or "name"
server = input("Please enter a name you wish to call this server ") or "server"
prompt = name + "@" + server


def error(choice):
        print(choice + ": command not found")
        commands()


def clear():
        os.system("cls")
        commands()


def commands():
        while 1 > 0:
                choice = input(prompt)
                {'clear': clear}.get(choice, error(choice))()

commands()
```

When running this code, no matter what I enter the dictionaries .get function always returns an error. When I enter 'clear' the script should go to that function. Does anyone have an idea why this does not work correctly? Thanks.

Comment: You have a lot of recursion going on there. How will it ever end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to actually call `error(choice)`.

You can [partially apply parameters to a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) but leave it to be called later:

```
>>> def error(choice):
...     print(choice + ': command not found')

>>> from functools import partial
>>> func = partial(error, choice='asdf')
>>> func()
asdf: command not found
```

So you want:

```
{'clear': clear}.get(choice, partial(error, choice))()
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll always see the error, because all arguments to a function must be evaluated before the function is called. So `error(choice)` will be called to get its result before it is passed as the default value to `get()`.

Instead, leave out the default, and check it explicitly:

```
result = {'clear': clear}.get(choice)
if result:
    result()
else:
    error(choice)
```